# Review of electric circuit with Arduino

Tags: arduino, mosfet, circuit-design

I am currently working on a project for which I am in charge of the electronic circuit. Since I have never worked with electronics before, I am really desperate and unsure whether what I am doing is correct.

My goal is to heat and shape set the "SMA wire" by Joule heating. For this I have to come up with an Arduino controlled circuit that can heat the wire and depending on the temperature (measured by thermal camera) reached, I have to adapt the temperature again via adaptable voltage/current supply.

I have attached my design for the circuit.

[image]

Comment: It looks like it would work.

Comment: Why are you using a camera?  There are simpler ways to measure a temperature.  Are you measuring the temperature, or looking at how the SMA wire bends with the camera?

Comment: the goal is to shape set the wire using joule heating. the temperature is a parameter used for feedback on the transformation. Basically the current is rapidly switched on and off until the desired temperature is reached.

a temperature sensor would surely work as well, but my supervisor told me to use a thermal camera for tracking

Comment: I don't see that you need the analog to digital converter between the PC and the Arduino.  You can use serial communication from the PC to the Arduino.  The PC determines the temperature from the camera pictures, then sends a command to the Arduino - either "set PWM 57%" or "decrease PWM by 1%" or whatever seems clearest.  I'd probably consider just telling the Arduino "Temperature 175 degrees" then use a PID controller in the Arduino set the PWM duty cycle.

Comment: where does the "PMW 57%" come from?

Comment: Seems about right.

Comment: Hiya and welcome :-) It would help us if you elaborated on what SMA wire is, what shape setting is and why a camera is required rather than a temperature sensor... Hi again.

Comment: Hi :D sma = shape memory alloy, an alloy that can "remember" a certain shape for a specific temperature

shape setting = in order to give the wire the desired shape, that it shall remember for a specific temperature, the wire has to be preshaped and set in that shape beforehand

the camera is required to track the temperature of the wire, since the sma material is going though a tranformation, depending on temperature. the temperature is like the feedback to know what state of transformation the sma is

Comment: some classmates said that the TVS, capacitor and diode are unnecessary, what do gouus think? And that the battery is in need of grounding?

Comment: I wouldn't have put those in for a class project. The cap is especially pointless. Harmful even.

Comment: what do mean by cap? and why is that?

Comment: oh you mean the capacitor? So you would recommend leaving the capacitor out and the TVS and the diode as it is?

Comment: What I meant by  "PMW 57%" was that the PC would calculate the required PWM duty cycle and tell the Arduino to generate it.  That would have the controller running on the PC, with the Arduino just being the PWM generator.  It's probably cleaner to have the control software running on the Arduino with the PC only delivering the target temperature and the measure temperature.

Comment: If you were measuring the temperature with a sensor of some kind, then the whole thing could run on the Arduino - turn a dial for target temperature, PID controller in the Arduino measures the temperature and sets the PWM by itself.

Comment: The thermal camera just seems totally over the top, unless it is part of a computer vision requirement for the project or something.

Comment: @JRE As I understand, a fast sensor response time without physical contact and good resolution is required here. The camera solution will provide this.

Comment: The cap just charges up when the transistor is not conducting for no good reason, then when the transistor starts conducting it gets a big surge from discharging the transistor which also does nothing and can be bad for the transistor. The diode and TVS don't hurt but don't seem necessary here. If inductance was an issue then only the diode would be necessary.

Comment: wow thanks for all the great advices!
my teacher wants us to use a thermal camera but maybe I can ask if a sensor would be okas too.

Comment: From what I have read about thermal cameras, you should be able to read each pixel directly with the Arduino. You could read just the highest value or take an average over the pixels that correspond to the target. This might help: https://www.engineersgarage.com/how-to-use-a-thermal-camera-with-arduino/